# jQuery function loop don't stop after checkbox unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, checkbox

I have a checkbox, which starts a loop of a function called "next". So far that work's correctly. Unckecked box should stop the function loop. That doesn't work. I found in the stackoverflow-forum, that it is necessary to declare a variable of the Interval-ID outside the if-else-statement. No success. Any ideas? 
This is the code:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      var intervalID = 0; 
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
          var intervalID = setInterval(next, 400);         
         }
           else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
           clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
      }
  );
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I found in the stackoverflow-forum, that it is necessary to declare a variable of the Interval-ID outside the if-else-statement"*

There's a lot more to scopes than that. In your case, when you initialise a variable inside the function, it is only available inside that function. I would highly recommend reading up on scopes, there's a lot of good information out there that doesn't need to be repeated here. For example: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

You really need to run through your code to understand what's happening. Look at the code and think about it. Every time a checkbox is clicked, you are setting `intervalID` to `0`. So it's not at all surprising that the `clearInterval` function isn't working.

You need to store that variable *outside* of the entire click function, so it's accessible the next time the event is fired. Also, `else` will suffice. There's only 2 possible options; if the first check returns false then you know it isn't checked - you don't need to test it.

```
var intervalID = 0;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
    intervalID = setInterval( next, 400 );         
  }
  else {
    clearInterval( intervalID );
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much. Very annoying: I had already check puttig the `var intervalID = 0;` outside. But then forget to remove "var" in the loop :-/.